# Repeated data in html table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am struggling with `data-ng-repeat` in `AngularJS` for a bit complex (for a beginner like me) table.

Data I have is:

```
  $scope.test = [
       {store: "NYC store",
        comment: "comment1",
        prices: {
            "product1": "12",
            "product2": "10",
            "product3": "71"}
        },
       {store: "Texas store,
        comment: "comment2",
        prices: {
            "product1": "15",
            "product2": "9",
            "product3": "68"}
        },
      ];
```

And the table should look something like:

[image]

What I've tried:

```
<table style=" border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="data in test">{{ data.store }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in test[0].prices">
        <td>{{ val }}</td>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-ng-repeat="data in test">{{ data.comment }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the issue here is that I am not sure how to repeat all maps here, because now all I can do is exclusively repeat just `test[0].prices` but not all the array elements (i/e/ all maps).

Comment: do you have fix no of products?

Comment: Extract products first into separate array. But better normalize your data structure in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not really an Angular problem, but rather a problem in how you can loop to the data from the array into a table that is not shapped the same way.

The products are also not an array, but a list of properties on an object.

```
  <table style=" border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th data-ng-repeat="data in test">{{ data.store }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in test[0].prices">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="data in test">{{data.prices[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="data in test">{{ data.comment }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Se also https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Example: http://jsbin.com/kedezup/3/edit?html,js,output